# Displaying text with different color based on result from a computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Currently I have something along the lines of:

```
data(){
    return {
        summonerMatches: '',
    }
},
computed: {
    highestMultikill(){
        let highestMultikill = 0;

        for (let match of this.summonerMatches.matches) {
            if (highestMultikill < match.mainParticipant.stats.largestMultiKill) {
                highestMultikill = match.mainParticipant.stats.largestMultiKill
            }
        }

        return highestMultikill
    },
}
```

When I use this computed property in my template like this:

```
<p>{{ highestMultikill }}</p>
```

I render a number that symbolizes the highest multi kill of a user. Now I would like to somehow add a class to that `<p>` element based on the highestMultiKill. If highestMultiKill = 1, set a class that changes the color to blue, if highestMultiKill = 5, set a class that changes the color to red, etc.

I'm not sure how to do that with my current setup. I was thinking about having the computed property return an entire different `<p>`element based on the highestMultikill variable like this:

```
if (highestMultiKill == 1) {
    return <p class='blue'>highestMultiKill</p>
} else {
    return a different `<p>` element with a different class
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional class like this:

```
<p :class="highestMultiKill == 1 ? 'blue' : 'otherClass'">highestMultiKill</p>
```

See the [full documentation on conditional classes in Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) here.

By the way you should not initialize `summonerMatches` with a string if it's actually an object with reactive properties.

Comment: But what if the logic is longer, or there are multiple if elses?

Comment: As @sevensidedmarble suggests you can use a computed property in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with more complex logic and BEM-inspired class names:

```js
<template>
  <p :class="klass">{{ highestMultiKill }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { highestMultiKill: 0 };
  },
  computed: {
    klass() {
      return {
        score: true, // Always have a score class
        'score--low': this.highestMultiKill <= 2,
        'score--medium': this.highestMultiKill > 2 && this.highestMultiKill <= 5,
        'score--high': this.highestMultiKill > 5 && this.highestMultiKill <= 10,
        'score--blood-lust': this.highestMultiKill > 10,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.score {
  line-height: 2;
}

.score--low {
  color: blue;
}
.score--medium {
  color: pink;
}
.score--medium {
  color: red;
}
.score--medium {
  color: darkred;
}
</style>
```

The idea is that the `p` will have a class like: `score score--medium`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, if you have complex logic involving many variables and or classes, is something like this:

```
<p :class="killClass"></div>
```

```
computed: {
  killClass: function () {
    return {
      highestMultiKill >= 3 ? 'blue' : 'red'
    }
  }
}
```

If you have more classes/states then use an if statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

This sample can be of use:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==0" style="color:blue;" >content0</p>
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==1" style="color:red;" >content1</p>
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==2" style="color:green;" >content2</p>
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==3" style="color:yellow;" >content3</p> 
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==4" style="color:pink;" >content4</p>
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==5" style="color:aquamarine;" >content5</p>
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==6" style="color:blueviolet;" >content6</p>
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==7" style="color:brown;" >content7</p>
      <p v-if="this.computedValue==8" style="color:chartreuse;" >content8</p>
      <p v-else>content9</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.11.10/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      new Vue({
        el: '#container',
        data: {
          value: '',
        },
        computed: {
          computedValue: function() {
            var styleNumber = 0;/*return a number based on a logic*/

            return styleNumber; 
          }
        }
      });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```